# Multiple JOIN on more then 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables:

```
Cars
-----------------
CarBrand | Amount
 Honda   |  0
 Mitsu   |  5
 Ford    |  7

CarParts
--------------------
CarPartID | CarBrand
 001      |  Honda
 002      |  Mitsu
 003      |  Ford
 004      |  Ford
 005      |  Ford

Drivers
-----------------------
DriverName  |  CarBrand
 Tom        |  Ford
 John       |  Mitsu
 Mark       |  Mitsu
```

And I need following data in result:

CarBrand | PartsAmount | DriversAmount

Is it possible? Count after full join doesn't work there...

Comment: looks like your homework, could you post your efforts before we give you an answer please?

Comment: select 

DEVICE2M1.LOGICAL_NAME,
SUBSCRIPM1.STATUS as subscribe,
SUBSCRIPM1.SUBSCRIBERTYPE as usersubscribe,
INCIDENTSM1.AFFECTED_ITEM as call,
INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME as call_date,
PROBSUMMARYM2.AFFECTED_ITEM as incident,
CM3RM2.AFFECTED_ITEM as change


from DEVICE2M1
full join SUBSCRIPM1 on DEVICE2M1.LOGICAL_NAME = SUBSCRIPM1.SERVICENAME
full join INCIDENTSM1 on DEVICE2M1.LOGICAL_NAME = INCIDENTSM1.AFFECTED_ITEM
full join PROBSUMMARYM2 on DEVICE2M1.LOGICAL_NAME = PROBSUMMARYM2.AFFECTED_ITEM
full join CM3RM2 on DEVICE2M1.LOGICAL_NAME = CM3RM2.AFFECTED_ITEM

where DEVICE2M1.SUBTYPE = 'Service'

Comment: can't see any relation between this select and your question, you aren't even querying the tables you described in the question

Comment: after all these joins I try to use COUNT, but it's pointless...

Comment: @Anton - there's an *edit* link that lets you *update* your question. When you're modifying your question, you can use tools such as the `{}` code button which lets you lay out pieces of code and turns on the syntax highlighter - things you can't do in comments.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Thanks!

tr3
The idea was to combine all tables in one and then make calculation on it, but turns out that excessive rows being produced. So I need to make calculation before combine them to a result table.

Comment: i posted a couple of queries, check the link in my answer

Comment: Not the solution to your problem about the usage of Count but as a side note, it's pointless to use a FULL JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN or a regular INNER JOIN on the table DEVICE2M1 while at the same time using the Where condition "DEVICE2M1.SUBTYPE = 'Service'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a couple of ways to do what you want: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1de40/2)

```
select c.CarBrand, j.parts, k.drivers
from
   Cars c
cross apply
(
    select count(*)
    from CarParts cp
    where cp.CarBrand = c.CarBrand
) j (parts)
cross apply
(
    select count(*)
    from Drivers d
    where d.CarBrand = c.CarBrand
) k (drivers);
```

or

```
select
  c.CarBrand,
  (select count(*) from CarParts cp where cp.CarBrand = c.CarBrand) as Parts,
  (select count(*) from Drivers d where d.CarBrand = c.CarBrand) as Drivers
from
  Cars C
```

is this ok for you?

Comment: wow! it works!
sorry for a late response, I was trying you method on a real data
Thanks a lot!